# Evaluating the output of a condition in R?

Tags: r, function, if-statement

In the below R function, I was wondering how I could get R to evaluate whether the object `input` outputs `n` or `es`?

**Note:** I will need to know the exact output of `input`, so I canNOT be using `identical()` etc.

Here is what I have tried with no success:

```
d = function(n, es){
    input = if(length(n) > 1) n else if(length(es) > 1) es else n
    if(input == n) cat("yes") else cat("No")    # IF `input` is `n` cat("yes") otherwise cat("no")
}

d(n = c(2, 3), es = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `if(identical(n, input)) cat("yes") else cat("No")`. `==` cannot be